# upgrading from postgresql 9.1 to 9.3 on ubuntu server with data intact

Tags: postgresql

I have my production server(ubuntu 13.10) running with postgresql 9.1.

I want to use few features of 9.3, hence want to upgrade.

Could someone help me with upgrading from 9.1 to 9.3 so that there is a downtime of not more than 30 mins. or so?

Prime concern is preventing a data loss or file redundancy.

Comment: The only way to do a near-zero downtime migration is to use replication via 3rd party tools. You can do a *low* downtime upgrade by making a backup and doing an in-place `pg_upgrade`. You should test it on the backup first. See the PostgreSQL documentation for details on upgrades, and the Ubuntu docs at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL

Comment: the link does not talk about upgrading from 9.1 to 9.3.Could you suggest ways to upgrade with say 30 mins. downtime?

Comment: You may want to post this on Server Fault not Superuser. They discuss more server related issues and you may find someone more accustomed with MySQL on a Ubuntu Server.

Comment: @DionPezzimenti Or dba.stackexchange.com, preferably.